# MongoDb.Driver 2.14.1 "Duplicate 'Content' items were included" when using MongoDb.Bson in shared project (.Net SDK 6.0.101)

Tags: .net, mongodb

Project setup with mongodb NuGets:

- Backend project with MongoDb.Driver & MongoDb.Driver.Core
- Shared project with Mongodb.Bson (which is referenced in backend!)

I am getting the following build error after updating nugets from **2.13.3** to **2.14.1**:

```
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.Shared.targets(213, 5):[NETSDK1022] Duplicate 'Content' items were included.
The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default.
You can either remove these items from your project file, or set the 'EnableDefaultContentItems' property to 'false' if you want to explicitly include them in your project file.
For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicititems.

The duplicate items were:
'C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver.core\2.14.1\build\..\runtimes\win\native\libzstd.dll'
'C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver.core\2.14.1\build\..\runtimes\win\native\snappy32.dll'
'C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver.core\2.14.1\build\..\runtimes\win\native\snappy64.dll'
'C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver.core\2.14.1\build\..\runtimes\linux\native\libsnappy64.so'
'C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver.core\2.14.1\build\..\runtimes\linux\native\libzstd.so'
'C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver.core\2.14.1\build\..\runtimes\osx\native\libsnappy64.dylib'
'C:\Users\**\.nuget\packages\mongodb.driver.core\2.14.1\build\..\runtimes\osx\native\libzstd.dylib'
```

Rollback to **2.13.3** solves the problem. Is this a bug, or does anyone have an idea, what is going wrong here?

Comment: Having the same issue :-(

Comment: Just hit this today!

Comment: Same same since 2.14.1

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the first version to solve it is `2.18.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that at least from version 2.18.0 the error "Duplicate 'Content' items were included" has been fixed.

So if anyone has added `<EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>` to the project file as well, you can/should remove it now.